# REST and SOAP web service security with role based authentication and login in JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ws-security

I want to implement role based authorization and identity in my web services. i it's the first time i try to do this with j2ee. i am running jboss 6.4 nad j2ee 7.
what i a, trying to understand :

1- how to implement role based security. My web services will expose methods with certain security levels that are to be available to certain roles.

2- how to authenticate users of my web services given that the front end is HTML5 JS (mostly react and some pure JS)

3- how to throw encryption of soap envelopes and https in the mix

4- if i have a users DB, what type of security mechanisms or frameworks can i use in j2ee to enable role based security.

I appreciate if someone could give an example or point me to somewhere where i can read preferably sample code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is good but it violates requirements to new questions. You should ask more specific questions like "I have a problem with the following code" and not to ask for advices like "how should i implement smth". Posting questions like this one can only give you tons of downvotes.

Comment: I will also add that JBoss EAP 6.4 is not a Java EE 7 implementation

Comment: ok thanks and sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss runs good with [Picketlink](http://picketlink.org/). This framework can give you all security features you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for the tip but i see it only shows basic how to examples about authentication and authorization, i cannot figure out how to combine the two.. basically i want to protect my rest endpoints from unauthenticated and unauthorized access, so if an unauthenticated user makes a call, it gets rejected and if an authenticated user tries to access something he is not supposed to access, also gets denied.
like a role based approach, only users in a role are able to access resources protected by or available for the role. i'll keep going through the examples to see what i can find.

Comment: Ok, good luck! If you're looking for ideas, i could suggest you something like generating random token on each log-in, keeping it both on server and client side, then using it as a request parameter, and returning 403 if they're not equal. Then you have to check the authorization (can be done with Picketlink or manually) and return 403 if user if not authorized.